# Print a file content from a tar.gz archive

Tags: linux, bash, tar, archive

I would like to print a single file content from a tar.gz archive.

I know I can list the files from the archive like so:

```sh
$ tar -tf openjdk-17.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
[...snip...]
jdk-17.0.2/lib/server/libjsig.so
jdk-17.0.2/lib/server/libjvm.so
jdk-17.0.2/lib/src.zip
jdk-17.0.2/lib/tzdb.dat
jdk-17.0.2/release      <---- print the content of this file (with 'cat' or 'more')
```

I want to print the content of the file `jdk-17.0.2/release`, preferably without extracting it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vim instead, and then browse using your cursor:

```
vim openjdk-17.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
```

Alternatively, have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392885/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-from-the-command-l) thread.

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract that one file and write it to stdout

```
tar --extract -O --file=openjdk-17.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz jdk-17.0.2/release
```

I do not know how you print on your system but you can pipe the output to lp if that is set up.

```
tar --extract -O --file=openjdk-17.0.2_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz jdk-17.0.2/release | lp
```